# iphone: Numeric keyboard with decimal for text input for Web Applicaiton

Tags: iphone, html

Iphone type=number step=any truncates the trailing zero's after the decimal point.

There is a case here :

I wish to enter a amount $28.90 also in another box $28.9 ( 90 and 9 ), But iphone truncates both to 28.9.

Can any one help me to solve this?.

Comment: when you say box you mean textfields, right?

Comment: Yes @rptwsthi, I mean text input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [fmt setFormat:@"0.##"];
  NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:28.902]]);
  NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:28.9]]);
  NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:28.0]]);
```

Comment: first you need to convert the string to nsnumber

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But I forgot to mention that I am working on web application for iphone